# Pinia undefined state inside computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, store, vue-composition-api, pinia

I try to use Pinia with composition Api and define store like:

```
export const useOfficeStore = defineStore("office", () => {
  const rooms = ref(new Map());
  rooms.value.set("first", {
    id: "first",
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    pers: null,
  });
  const freeRooms = computed(function (state) {
    console.log("Invoked free rooms", state);
    return this.rooms;
  });
  return {
    rooms,
    freeRooms,
  };
});
```

In my component I import the state like this:

```
import { useOfficeStore } from "@/stores/counter";

const store = useOfficeStore();

function mark() {
    console.log("Free", store.freeRooms);
}
```

When I call the computed property, I face those logs:

```
Invoked free rooms undefined
Free undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting undefined because you are mixing two syntaxes. Here is the example from the [pinia docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores):

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
  const count = ref(0)
  function increment() {
    count.value++
  }

  return { count, increment }
})
```

In the case of composition API you can't use **this** to access *state properties* and the computed functions do no longer get *state* as the argument. So in your case the function should look like this:

```
const freeRooms = computed(function () {
  console.log("Invoked free rooms");
  return rooms.value;
});
```